# Can I add same sidebar section groupings for all workspace users?

Tags: slack

We have a workspace on the standard plan - can now add sidebar sections (amazing feature).

I have set-up my own workspace using sections and dragged all channels into relevant sidebar sections. But this only applies to me - all other users do not see my "section architecture".

Right now it is possible for all users of the workspace to customize their own section architecture. I would like to set my architecture as the default for all users.

Is there any way that I can set up channel & section architecture and make that default to all other users of the same workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have realised that each user of a workspace sets their own sidebar sections. NOT possible to set up "master" sidebar sections for all users of the workspace to automatically adopt.